# mapping two arrays of equivalent length by object attributes javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, jsobject

I have two arrays:

Array 1:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Bob',
        traits: {
            id: 1
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Karl',
        traits: {
            id: 2
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Joseph',
        traits: {
            id: 3
        }
    }
]
```

Array 2:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Karl',
        user_id: 2,
        dog: 'Rottweiler'
    }, {
        name: 'Joseph',
        user_id: 3,
        dog: 'Poodle'
    }, {
        name: 'Bob',
        user_id: 1,
        dog: 'Puppy'
    }
]
```

Desired outcome:

I want to be able to merge the second array into the first array by finding what element user_id matches with id and then adding the object to array.

For example:

**array 1 obj**

```
{
    name: 'Bob',
    traits: {
        id: 1
    }
}
```

Since the id matches with **array 2 obj** user_id:

```
{
    name: 'Bob',
    user_id: 1,
    dog: 'Puppy'
}
```

Final outcome will be:

```
{
    name: 'Bob',
    traits: {
        name: 'Bob',
        user_id: 1,
        dog: 'Puppy'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
arr2.forEach((obj) => {
    const idx = arr1.findIndex((o) => o.traits.id === obj.user_id);
    if (idx !== -1) {
        arr1[idx] = { ...arr1[idx], traits: { ...obj } }
    }
})

console.log(arr1[0]) // { name: 'Bob', traits: { name: 'Bob', user_id: 1, dog: 'Puppy' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the second array into a map keyed by `user_id`, and then iterate the first array. Find the corresponding object in the map, and spread the matching object value into the `traits` property:

```js
let arr1 = [{name: 'Bob',traits: {id: 1}},{name: 'Karl',traits: {id: 2}},{name: 'Joseph',traits: {id: 3}}];
let arr2 = [{name: 'Karl', user_id: 2,dog: 'Rottweiler'},{name: 'Joseph', user_id: 3,dog: 'Poodle'},{name: 'Bob',user_id: 1,dog: 'Puppy'}];

let map = new Map(arr2.map(item => [item.user_id, item]));

let result = arr1.map(item => {
    let traits = map.get(item.traits.id);
    return traits ? { ...item, traits} : item;
});

console.log(result);
```

As lookup in a map has an amortised time complexity of O(1), this is more efficient than finding the key in the array on every iteration (like with calling `find`).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Just map over the first array and find the element with `obj.traits.id` in the `arr2`. then return the desired result.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    name: "Bob",
    traits: {
      id: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    name: "Karl",
    traits: {
      id: 2,
    },
  },
  {
    name: "Joseph",
    traits: {
      id: 3,
    },
  },
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    name: "Karl",
    user_id: 2,
    dog: "Rottweiler",
  },
  {
    name: "Joseph",
    user_id: 3,
    dog: "Poodle",
  },
  {
    name: "Bob",
    user_id: 1,
    dog: "Puppy",
  },
];

const result = arr1.map((obj) => {
  const { name, traits } = obj;
  const isExist = arr2.find((o) => o.user_id === traits.id);
  if (isExist) {
    return { name, traits: { ...isExist } };
  }
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = [
    {
        name: 'Bob',
        traits: {
            id: 1
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Karl',
        traits: {
            id: 2
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Joseph',
        traits: {
            id: 3
        }
    }
    ];

    let b = [
        {
            name: 'Karl',
            user_id: 2,
            dog: 'Rottweiler'
        }, {
            name: 'Joseph',
            user_id: 3,
            dog: 'Poodle'
        }, {
            name: 'Bob',
            user_id: 1,
            dog: 'Puppy'
        }
    ];
    
    a.map(aobj =>{
    let sameIdObj = b.find( bobj => bobj.user_id === aobj.traits.id )
    sameIdObj && (aobj.traits =  sameIdObj)
    })

    console.log(a);
```